# Circularity on Unique Readability for Terms

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic

I have begun self-studying Logic (I am a numerical physicist), and I am stuck at the very beginning. I have a problem with the proof of the Unique Readability Theorem for Terms in First Order Logic (but the same issue applies to formulas). The proof is done using Induction on the Length (or Rank) of Terms. However to do that one need first to prove that the recursive definition for the Length (or Rank) of a Term, is indeed a function (i.e. each term has a unique Length). To prove this, one needs to assume that terms can only be written in one way. If I assume that a term can be written in two different ways, there is nothing in the recursive definition of length that prevents it from having two different values for length. This to me look circular!

I can prove that Unique Readability is equivalent to Uniqueness of Length, but I cannot prove both. I am under the impression that, either one assumes order in the set of Terms, taking uniqueness of recursive definition as a axiom, and prove induction, or assumes induction as an axiom and prove uniqueness of recursive definition (order).

Is there a way to prove both Unique Readability and Uniqueness of Length? And if not, why this is not stated clearly?  I have read dozens of first order logic book, but none seems to consider this issue. I apologize if this is a stupid question. It is the first time I am using StackExchange, but I am really stuck.

Thank you in advance.

I will try to articulate:

I am not using a specific book, but browsing a lot of them and trying to re-organize their content in a way that can convince myself, because I want to see if I can recover those results. There is something similar for strings in Cori & Lascaux.

Unique readability for terms begin by showing that no term can be a proper initial segment of another. This is done via induction.

To use induction you need order (you need to be able to tell that a term is shorter that another). You start by assuming that your induction hypothesis holds for all terms of length n and then prove it holds for terms of length n+1, by reduction ab absurdum (you assume that on a term of length n+1 it is violated and derive that is should be violated also for terms of length n contradicting the induction hypothesis).

You can see that you are making a lot of untold assumptions here (all term have a length, the length of a term is unique, all length can be compared, all length are positive integers .....). Either you assume all of them (and this to me amount to elevating uniqueness of length to an axiom), or you need to provide a definition of length that ensures all of these assumptions. You cannot say that they hold just because you can write down terms that satisfy them. The set of term is infinite, so the fact that a property holds for any finite subset is not enough.

The definition is done via recursion:
if a term is a variable or constant its length is 1.
if a term $t= f t_1 ....t_n$ (and $f$ is an $n-$ary function symbol) and the length of each term $t_i$ is $l_i$ then the length of $t$ is $1+\sum l_i$

Obviously if the term $t$ can be written in two ways (say $ft_1t_2t_3$ and $ft_4t_5t_6$), this recursive definition does not ensure that its length is unique, unless $l_1=l_4,l_2=l_5,l_3=l_6$, but why should this be? How can I prove it? For example van Dalen Thm 2.1.6 makes it clear that defining a relation by recursion is not enough to prove that it is a function (i.e. uniqueness).

Comment: Why circular? Unicity of lenght means that term "pluto" has a specific lenght, not that we cannot have two terms "pippo" and "pluto" with the same lenght.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You should state which textbook you're using, and where the relevant definitions and proofs occur, so thar we can take a look to see how the proof goes. While proving unique readability by induction on length does not require circular reasoning of the kind you describe, your particular textbook might happen to contain a dodgy proof, or you could be misreading one of the definitions there.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku yes but Induction is an Axiom in Peano Arithmetic. So you assume that induction holds. If instead you want to prove Induction as a Theorem, you need to assume well-ordering if I am not mistaken. You cannot prove both well ordering and induction.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. OK "pluto" has length 5, but can you show me that every possible sting (even a string with so many symbols that written down will be larger than the size of the universe) has a unique value for its length?

Comment: Obviously if the term t can be written in two ways (say ft1t2t3 and ft4t5t6)... They are **two** terms: a *terms* is a sequence of symbols: $+xy$ and $(x+y)$ are two different strings.

Comment: @ Z. A. K. no specific book, but I am following what Cori & Lascaux do for strings. You have a similar issue there. You need to prove that strings can be written only in one way, you do this by induction on the length of string, that you define via recursion. But somehow they do not care of showing that the recursive definition is unique.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I am quoting from van Dalen "In concrete applications Definition by Recursion is usually rather easily seen to be a correct principle. However, in general one has to prove the existence of a unique function satisfying the above equations."

Comment: @ Z. A. K. Various book I have read start defining by recursion the Length of a Term, and then proceed to prove Unique Readability by induction on Length of
terms. However in van Dalen I found this remark "In concrete applications Definition by Recursion is usually rather easily seen to be a correct principle. However, in general one has to prove the existence of a unique function satisfying the above equations.".... so I wandered how can I prove it, and failed to find a way that did not require Unique Readability.

Comment: As per second comment above, we have to start somewhere: specifically, we assume that we are able to count.

Comment: I conjecture that your mention of "the recursive definition for the length" arose from one book and that the proof of unique readability by induction on length came from another book.

Comment: Cori & Lascaux define *length* of a word at page xviii and obviously they do not define it by induction.

Comment: What is an example of a term written in multiple ways?

Answer (score 2):

Unique readability is not required for unique length. An expression like $P \lor Q \land R$ has no unique reading, but it does have a unique length.

This one counterexample shows that Uniqueness of Length does not imply Uniqueness of Readability, let alone that these two are equivalent.

I also want to note that you talk about terms being written in two different ways, but there is no such thing: a term is a string of symbols … any other string of symbols is a different term … or not a term at all. Note that we are talking about Uniqueness of Readability, not Uniqueness of Writability.

Comment: The fact that one term (or any finite set or terms) has a unique length does not imply that all terms have unique length.

Comment: @NiccBucc True, but this one example does show that uniqueness of length does not require or imply uniqueness of readability. Indeed, you can prove uniqueness of length in and of itself.